# Bootstrap Nod Validation Plugin And Iframs

Tags: validation, twitter-bootstrap, iframe

I'm using bootstrap-wysihtml5 editor on my form which creates iframe element.

```
<iframe class="wysihtml5-sandbox" width="0" height="0" frameborder="0" security="restricted" allowtransparency="true" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" name="for_nod" src="#" style="display: inline-block; background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255); border-collapse: separate; border-color: rgb(204, 204, 204); border-style: solid; border-width: 1px; clear: none; float: none; margin: 0px 0px 10px; outline: 0px none rgb(0, 0, 0); outline-offset: 0px; padding: 4px 6px; position: static; top: auto; left: auto; right: auto; bottom: auto; z-index: auto; vertical-align: middle; text-align: start; -moz-box-sizing: content-box; box-shadow: 0px 1px 1px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.075) inset; border-radius: 4px 4px 4px 4px; width: 750px; height: 300px;">
<html>
    <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link href="/js/plug-ins/bootstrap-wysihtml5/rtl/rtl-editor.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <style type="text/css">
    </head>
    <body class="wysihtml5-editor" contenteditable="true" spellcheck="true" style="background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255); color: rgb(85, 85, 85); cursor: text; font-family: "Helvetica Neue",Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif; font-size: 14px; font-style: normal; font-variant: normal; font-weight: 400; line-height: 20px; letter-spacing: normal; text-align: start; text-decoration: none; text-indent: 0px; text-rendering: optimizelegibility; word-break: normal; word-wrap: break-word; word-spacing: 0px;">
        simple text
        <br>
    </body>
</html>
</iframe>
```

I need to validate that body element inside the iframe isn't empty using Nod validation plugin.

the problem is that Nod validation plugin accepts jquery selectors TEXT for setting validation rules for elements , NOT objects - I can get the iframe  object using $("iframe").content().find("body") but the validation logic will not work.

I have tried to set submit button *onclick* event handler to handle the validation of the iframe manually , the problem was that if the rules used by Nod passes ,then the custom validation function will have no effect if it returned true or false values.

anyway to get around this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have been solved my issue by creating non-displayed textarea element and then using custom events feature in order to listen to change event of iframe body , and minplulated the hidden textarea content to be the same.
nod rules has been applied to the hidden textarea.

I am not sure if this is the perfect solution but I had no choice :) for the moment.

***the custom contentchange event code***

```
/*
 * custom-change-event  
 *
 *  This custom event is used for those elements  
 *  that has no support for default change event
 *  like : body , div ,span, ....
 *
 *
 */

    var interval;

    jQuery.fn.contentchange = function (fn) {
        return this.on('contentchange', fn);
    };

    jQuery.event.special.contentchange = {
        setup: function (data, namespaces, eventHandle) {
            var self = this,
                $this = $(this),
                $originalContent = $this.text();
            interval = setInterval(function () {
                if ($originalContent != $this.text()) {
                    $originalContent = $this.text();
                    jQuery.event.special.contentchange.handler.call(self);
                }
            }, 500);
        },
        teardown: function (namespaces) {
            clearInterval(interval);
        },
        handler: function (event) {
            $(this).trigger('contentchange');
        }
    };
```